# Is there a way to split a string using loops and without using any function other than charAt(0)?

Tags: java, string, loops, char

I couldn't find anything posted previously that matched this problem. I'm tasked with splitting a string and then return the split without using any of the functions you'd normally use to do so. I can do it for words I know the length of, but I'm trying to find a way to generalise it, if it's at all possible.

There isn't much else to say despite specifying what we aren't allowed to do: Any other method from the String class beside length(), charAt(), equals(), equalsIgnoreCase(), toLowerCase(), and toUpperCase().In particular, you are NOT allowed to use substring(), split(), contains(), indexOf(), or lastIndexOf().

I figured I should use a loop and an if statement to find where the word (in this case an email address) should split (by the @ sign), extract the individual characters, and then concatenate them into a string. What I'm wondering is if there is a way to generalise it so that I can extract charAt(i-n), instead of at i-1, i-2, i-3, etc. I feel like I am on the right track but I'm a bit stuck.

```
public static String getDomain (String s){
    String domain = "domain";
    int wordLength = s.length();   
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<= wordLength-1; i++) {
      if (s.charAt(i) == '@') {                    
        domain = (""+s.charAt(i-3)+s.charAt(i-2)+s.charAt(i-1));
              System.out.println(domain);
              return domain;
              }
    }
    return domain;
```

This will return any three-letter word that precedes '@' as a string, but is there a way to make it more general? Should I use more loops? Something nested?

Comment: Is your end goal to basically recreate the `split` function? So if I enter `"example@domain.com` then you get an _array_ as your output of `["example", "domain.com"]` ?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: Any efficiency considerations here?

Comment: None at all other than it's nice if it looks sorta nice.

Comment: So only the String class can be used?

Answer (score 0):

This could be one solution:

```
public static String getDomain (String s){
    String domain = ""; // Consider using StringBuilder
    int index = 0;
    while(index < s.length()){
        if(s.charAt(index) == '@'){
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
        domain += "" + s.charAt(i);
    }

    return domain;
}
```

The index will be incremented, until it reaches the @-Symbol. Then we will concatenate every character till the index.

Another way (with only one loop):

```
public static String getDomain (String s){
    String domain = ""; // Consider using StringBuilder
    int index = 0;
    while(index < s.length()){
        if(s.charAt(index) != '@'){
            domain += "" + s.charAt(index);
        }else{
            return domain;
        }
        index++;
    }

    return ""; // Return an empty String if there is no @
}
```

Comment: why not do both at once?

Comment: Lol dmain in an email is after `@` sign, username is before it. :)

Comment: Yeah you're right. I was just trying to keep the variable names to cause no confusion

Answer (score 0):

## Splitting using ArrayList:

You can use an `ArrayList` which will store your results. An array list is essentially like an array, however, it is dynamic, so you can add/remove items from it without having to declare a size for it.

Below, I have modified your function a little. Instead of always splitting by `@` you can pass in your own delimiter (the thing you split the string by) as well as the string you want to be split.

Read the code comments below to get a better understanding on how it works:

```
public static ArrayList<String> mySplit(String toSplit, char del) {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(); // create an empty array list to store/hold the result

    String currentWord = ""; // create a string which will hold the current word we are looking to add to the array
    for(int i = 0; i < toSplit.length(); i++) { // loop through every letter in the toSplit word
        char currentChar = toSplit.charAt(i); // get the current character

        if(currentChar != del) { // if the current character doesn't equal the "splitting character" then add it to our currentWord variable
            currentWord += currentChar; // add the current character to the end of our currentWord string
        } else { // the current char is the "splitting character"
            result.add(currentWord); // add the current word to the results array
            currentWord = ""; // set the current word back to empty (so the next word can use it)
        }
    }
    result.add(currentWord);
    return result;
}
```

Then in your `main` you can use the function like so:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    ArrayList<String> splitDomain = mySplit("example@domain.com", '@');
    // Print the result from the function
    System.out.println(splitDomain.get(0)); 
    System.out.println(splitDomain.get(1));   
}
```

This will result in:

```
example
domain.com
```

**Note:** In order to use an `ArrayList` you need to first import it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

---

## Splitting without ArrayList:

If you cannot use `ArrayList`s then you need to calculate how big your array needs to be that you'll eventually return.

In order to do that you can use a function like this:

```
public static int countCharacter(String toCount, char character) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < toCount.length(); i++) {
        if(toCount.charAt(i) == character) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The above will count how many of a particular character there is in a given string. This can be used to then tell you how large your output array should be. (ie, if there is one `@` then the output should be an array of at least 2 in length).

Using the above function with arrays, you can modify your `mySplit` function to work without ArrayLists:

```
public static String[] mySplit(String toSplit, char del) {
    String[] result = new String[countCharacter(toSplit, del)+1]; // create an empty array with the amount of empty slots required to fit each splitted word.

    String currentWord = "";
    int indexToAdd = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < toSplit.length(); i++) { // loop through every letter in the toSplit word
        char currentChar = toSplit.charAt(i); // get the current character

        if(currentChar != del) { // if the current character doesn't equal the "splitting character" then add it to our currentWord variable
            currentWord += currentChar; // add the current character to the end of our currentWord string
        } else { // the current char is the "splitting character"
            result[indexToAdd] = currentWord; // add the current word to the results array
            currentWord = ""; // set the current word back to empty (so the next word can use it)
            indexToAdd++; // increment to the next index
        }
    }

    result[indexToAdd] = currentWord;
    return result;
}
```

You can then get the resulting array (the split array) in your `main` like so:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    String[] splitDomain = mySplit("example@domain.com@", '@');
    // Print the result from the function
    System.out.println(splitDomain[0]);
    System.out.println(splitDomain[1]);
}
```

Comment: Since I'm only using the method for one word, would it work to ignore arrays altogether and only use currentWord += currentChar (feels unlikely)? I have never used arrays before and this assignment serves as a form of introduction to Strings so I don't quite know what's possible. 
I have tried trying it out but I'm frankly too tired at the moment. Thank you in any case.

Comment: @AlexanderElg yeah, its possible without using arrays, but you need to clearly define what the output of your function should be. For example, if you enter "example@domain.com" what would the output be? If its just a string like you mentioned how would you like it to look? Eg: like this: `"example,domain"` or this: `"example"` (just return the thing before the `@`) or just return the thing after the `@`. (ie: "domain.com"). 
Depending on what you want to output will make the function more straightforward/complex, so it's important to clearly outline what you want it to return (output).

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you for the if (currenChar != del). That was what was needed

Answer (score 0):

Either I don't understand your question, but why don't you just use `substring()`:

```
public static String getDomain(String email) {
    for (int i = 0, length = email.length(); i < length; i++) {
        if (email.charAt(i) == '@') {
            return email.substring(i + 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

If you can't use `substring()`, you're still able to use a similar functionallity using `new String(char[], int, int)`:

```
public static String getDomain(String email) {
    char[] chars = email.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, length = chars.length; i < length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == '@') {
            return new String(chars, i + 1, length - i - 1);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 *  Implemention using java without some of methods, eg: indexOf/substring/xxx
 *  allowed: length, toCharArray, StringBuffer
 *  forbid: indexOf、substring
 */
public static ArrayList<String> mySplit(String toSplit, String del) {
  ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
  char[] target = del.toCharArray();
  String currentWord = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < toSplit.length(); i++) {
    int x = i, y = 0;
    String temp = "";
    while (y < target.length && target[y] == toSplit.charAt(x)){
        temp += toSplit.charAt(x);
        x ++;
        y ++;
    }
    if (x == i){
        temp += toSplit.charAt(x);
    }
    if (y < target.length ){
        // 丢失的要找补回来
        currentWord += temp;
    }
    else if(y == target.length){
        i = i + y - 1;
        result.add(currentWord);
        currentWord = "";
    }
    else{
        // 匹配成功
        result.add(currentWord);
        currentWord = "";
    }
  }
  result.add(currentWord);
  return result;
}
```